# How to make object use in whole application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

To give better idea for this question :

I make one Java EE (Spring MVC) application.

Our Question : To make one object and this object use whole application ( server start to server stop ) and this object have minimum 20-25 class bean. And this Object use in session scope (that mean user login to logout).And this object have all user . And our application have 10000-50000 user .

So can i store object in session ? OR can i store object in server memory (To make bean with MAP variable and using @autowaired) OR you have better idea , give me ..

Thanks,
kamlesh

Answer (score 0):

is this session scope or application scope?  if application scope, I would look at in-memory caches with possibly disk based backup (hazelcast/redis/ehcache).  You can remove data from the caches as needed.

Comment: but this object use every 15 sec. so i asked it . this object scope is session scope.when session remove then this object is remove ....

Comment: You also said "server start to server stop".

Comment: But all user have this object so i asked stackoverflow's user for give better idea ..........

Comment: @kamlesh - you can still use an in-memory cache for that purpose in my opinion - and remove the value from the cache once the session expires.  best of luck